# How to create a notification message like Whatsapp?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, notifications, real-time

Here is the example case I'm curious about:

let's say, 2 people chat using Whatsapp, Mike and Andy.
While Mike is waiting for Andy to reply his chat, he close his chat room with Andy, and goes to another chat room, with Tom. 
While Mike is texting Tom, Andy is sending the reply, then, what happen in Mike's phone is a push notification appear (you got a message from Andy).
But if Andy send the reply while Mike is still on the chat screen with Andy, the message won't come as a push notification, but as a real time message.
So, how do Whatsapp handle this condition? it's like the push notification know in which Screen is Mike currenly in.

Comment: Try using Firebase.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion @Felix,
but may you explain, hows logic behind it?

Comment: Just use Google. Trust me on that one.

Comment: alright, thx! @Felix

Answer (score 0):

Push message is caught by application before it is shown to the user and if the user isn't the good, I suppose app send notification (and it appears to user).

Comment: so in other word, push message received by app, and before it's displayed, app check if it's a good user or no?
if yes, then show the notifications, if no, then ignore?

Comment: Yes, I suppose. In my case, I send notification Google Server (GCM) and it send notification to my app. I need receiver which caught GCM's message and after my app can do everything with this message.
In this case, if it's good user, app just update chat and if no, display notification.

Comment: You can set that up when you're using Google Firebase. Just look it up. It's one of the easiest libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I dont Know if that helps u but in my chat application every chat has an id when the class chat is called ( When user opens a chat) and saves his current Id in a static variable when a new message comes in it checks wether this variable equals the chatid the message was Send to if it does itll use a broadcast to add another message to the chatview if not it sends a notification.